# How to disable touch-pad while using electron app?

Tags: node.js, electron

I am working with online exam system and I have built one electron desktop app for candidate to take the exam. I try to block or disable the touch-pad in order to prevent the 3 fingers and other. so they can't switch to browser and other tool to cheat. so if anyone know the way to prevent it please help me to fix this problems. Thank you before hand.

Comment: Can't they just use another computer / phone to cheat then? This seems redundant

Comment: @fkajzer, yes bro that kind of action we can prevent it but the thing now we focus on disable touch-pad